# Converting an iPhone app to universal; bounds vs frames

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to convert an iPhone application to work universally (on both iPhones and iPads). I've managed to get the frame to re-size correctly, but it seems like the bounds (the part the user can actually interact with) isn't re-sizing appropriately with it. So, for instance, a UIWebView will be drawn in the correct dimensions, but I can only interact with it within a smaller confine the size of an iPhone screen.

Any thoughts what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

How are you re-sizing this view?  Is it in an xib with autoresizing mask set to properly expand?  If so something else is going wrong.  I just tried making a sample project with a webview, where the xib is sized for iPhone.  I then marked the application as universal, and it runs just fine in the iPad simulator with all areas touchable.